# Java inheritance and super() isn't working as expected

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

For a homework assignment, I'm working with the following. It's an assigned class structure, I know it's not the best design by a long shot.

```
Class           | Extends         | Variables
--------------------------------------------------------
Person          | None            | firstName, lastName, streetAddress, zipCode, phone
CollegeEmployee | Person          | ssn, salary,deptName
Faculty         | CollegeEmployee | tenure(boolean)
Student         | person          | GPA,major
```

So in the Faculty class...

```
 public class Faculty extends CollegeEmployee
 {
      protected String booleanFlag;
      protected boolean tenured;
      public Faculty(String firstName, String lastName, String streetAddress,
                     String zipCode, String phoneNumber,String ssn,
                     String department,double salary)
      { 
           super(firstName,lastName,streetAddress,zipCode,phoneNumber,
                 ssn,department,salary);
           String booleanFlag = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                                (null, "Tenured (Y/N)?");
           if(booleanFlag.equals("Y"))
           tenured = true;
           else
           tenured = false;
       }
 }
```

It was my understanding that `super()` in `Faculty` would allow access to the variables in `CollegeEmployee` as well as `Person`. With the code above, it compiles fine when I ONLY include the `Person` variables. As soon as I try to use `ssn, department, or salary` I get the following compile errors.

```
 Faculty.java:15: error: constructor CollegeEmployee in class CollegeEmployee can not be applied to the given types:
            super(firstName,lastName,streetAddress,zipCode,phoneNumber,ssn,department,salary);
                                                                                            ^
Required: String,String,String,String,String
   Found: String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

I'm completely confused by this error...which is the actual and formal? `Person` has five arguments, `CollegeEmployee` has 3, so my guess is that something's funky with how the parameters are being passed...but I'm not quite sure where to begin fixing it. What am I missing?

Here's my CollegeEmployee class

```
 import java.util.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 //
 public class CollegeEmployee extends Person
 {
     protected String ssn;
     protected String sal;
     protected double annSalary;
     protected String department;
 //
     public CollegeEmployee(String firstName, String lastName, 
                            String streetAddress, String zipCode, 
                            String phoneNumber)
     {
          super(firstName,lastName,streetAddress,zipCode,phoneNumber);
          ssn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter SSN ");
          department = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                       (null, "Enter department: ");
          sal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter salary: ");
         annSalary = Double.parseDouble(sal);
     }
 //
     public void setSSN(String ssn)
     {         this.ssn = ssn;         }
     public void setAnnSalary(double annSalary)
     {        this.annSalary = annSalary;     }
     public void setDepartment(String department)
     {        this.department = department;    }
 //
     public String getSSN()
     {        return ssn;                }
     public double getAnnSalary()
     {        return annSalary;          }
     public String getDepartment()
     {        return department;         }
 //
     public void display()
     {
         super.display();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
         (null, "\nSSN: " + getSSN() + "\nAnnual Salary: " 
          + getAnnSalary() + "\nDepartment: " + getDepartment(), 
          "Information", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
     }
 }
```

Comment: One of the parameters of the constructor is `Department`, and you pass it to super as `department`.

Comment: Before correcting the code you should indent it, makes all the difference looking at indented code!!

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Made that case correction, and also a semicolon that I missed...but now there's another another related error... :|

Comment: @MrJames: indented...I had LF instead of CR when I cut and pasted.  D'oh!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You made an accidental `;` at the end of your constructor:

```
      public Faculty(String firstName, String lastName, String streetAddress,   String zipCode, String phoneNumber,String ssn,
           String Department,double salary); // <--- this has to go
```

And as pointed out in a comment you have `String Department` in your constructor, but you pass `department` (incorrect capitalization), rename your constructor argument to `String department`

Comment: Yes. Extra-semicolon makes the constructor-body an instance initialization block which is perfectly legal.

Comment: @heikkim: but the super call isn't correct in this instance initialization block, right? The initialization block is run after calling super()

Comment: You are right, it is not. Sorry for being ambiguous. I was simply referring to the location of the block, not the contents of the block.

Comment: glad to help, most things are simple once you know them :)

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `;` at the end of the constructor declaration line:

```
public Faculty(String firstName, String lastName, String streetAddress, String zipCode, String phoneNumber,String ssn,String Department,double salary);
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the ';' at the end of 'ment,double salary);'

```
public Faculty(String firstName, String lastName, String streetAddress, String zipCode, String phoneNumber,String ssn,String Department,double salary); <--- remove this
      {
```

Answer (score 1):

Your super class CollegeEmployee needs to have a constructor with this eight arguments, also the argument types should match

```
public class CollegeEmployee
{
    public CollegeEmployee(String firstName, String lastName, String streetAddress, String zipCode,
                        String phoneNumber, String ssn, String department, double salary)
    { 
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: @MrJames- I added my CollegeEmployee class...are you saying that the NEW variables (the three NOT inherited from `Person`) should be cast in the constructor parameters? and is that in addition to or instead of the variable declaration the appears ABOVE the constructor?

Comment: What I'm saying is that on your Faculty constructor you are calling super (that calls CollegeEmployee constructor) with eight arguments but on the class CollegeEmployee you don't have a constructor with eight parameters