# I can't figure out why my java inheritance isn't working

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

For homework, I'm working with the following three classes.

```
 Class           | Extends         | Variables
 --------------------------------------------------------
 Person          | None            | firstName, lastName, streetAddress, zipCode, phone
 CollegeEmployee | Person          | ssn, salary,deptName
 Faculty         | CollegeEmployee | tenure(boolean)
```

I am having trouble getting the Faculty constructor to properly use the data in the superclasses.

```
 import java.util.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 public class Faculty extends CollegeEmployee
 {
      protected String booleanFlag;
      protected boolean tenured;  
      public Faculty(String firstName, String lastName, String streetAddress, 
                     String zipCode, String phoneNumber, String ssn,
                     String department, double salary)
      {
           super(firstName,lastName,streetAddress,zipCode,phoneNumber,  
                 department,ssn,salary);
           String booleanFlag = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Tenured (Y/N)?");
           if(booleanFlag.equals("Y"))
              tenured = true;
           else
              tenured = false;
      }
      public void setTenure(boolean tenured)
      {  this.tenured = tenured;   }
      public boolean getTenured()
      {  return tenured;  }
      public void display()
      {
          super.display();
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tenured: " + tenured);
      }
 }
```

The `CollegeEmployee` class, from which `Faculty` descends, appears below.

```
 import java.util.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 public class CollegeEmployee extends Person
 {
     protected String ssn;
     protected String sal;
     protected double annSalary;
     protected String department;
     public CollegeEmployee(String firstName, String lastName, 
                            String streetAddress, String zipCode, 
                            String phoneNumber)
     {
         super(firstName,lastName,streetAddress,zipCode,phoneNumber);
           ssn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter SSN ");
          department = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter department: ");
          sal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter salary: ");
          annSalary = Double.parseDouble(sal);
     }  
     public void setFirstName(String firstName)
 {  this.firstName = firstName;  }
 public String getFirstName()
 {  return firstName;  }
     ... ETC ...  REMAINING GET/SET METHODS ELIMINATED FOR BREVITY.
```

The errors I'm getting point to a mismatch between parameters...`Faculty` calls eight parameters, but `CollegeEmployee` only has five. However, I'd think that by extending `CollegeEmployee` which extends `Person`, I'd have access to all eight fields by the time this class is called. As it's been pointed out, that's not the case. I only have the five fields from `Person`. So my obvious next question is how I get `ssn, department and salary` from `CollegeEmployee` to `Faculty`? That's the piece I'm missing. I've been poring over the Java Tutorials and experimenting for a couple hours, but still can't get what I need to do for the correction. Do I need to call the `People` variables, via `CollegeEmployee`, then instantiate the `CollegeEmployee` variables in `Faculty`? I'm getting really confused about what to do and desperately need some guidance...

Thanks loads, I'll be back in a few after I peruse the super() keywords section in the Tutorials.

Comment: Usability note: I'd be rather annoyed by the time i went through 9 dialogs, and start wondering if they'd ever end.  You might consider having a form that collects all the info and then creates the CollegeEmployee and returns it.  Even if you don't care about usability, consider the possibility of someone canceling out of the endless dialogs and leaving you with a half-initialized object.

Comment: Putting JOptiongPanes in a constructor is not a good idea, you should have all the information ready to go when you create a new object

Comment: I know...I know...but the assignment specifically says to put dialog boxes in the individual classes. I don't write the assignments, I just get confused by why they want us to do it in such an illogical manner.

Comment: @dwwilson66 Haha, don't worry, when you get to the real world client's will always ask for logical outcomes and give you good corresponding time frames...

Comment: Isn't this the same question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975109/java-inheritance-and-super-isnt-working-as-expected  ???

Comment: @dann.dev:   LOL!  as if :)  I guess it's better that he get used to the insanity now...

Comment: @MrJames...after all the fixes suggested earlier, this is still the one stumbling block I'm having; trying to rephrase it to clarify what I'm confused about.

Comment: @dann.dev been doing procedural programming for freakin' ever...I'm used to the insanity more than you know. However, it ~is~ frustrating to finally start to wrap my head around OO concepts, only to be assigned something that to me seems to be an awful sample of OO-ness.

Comment: @dwwilson66 It's an awful implementation, but I guess you could say it has 'some' value in that you can better track the order of events through the different JOptionPanes, and see how the class that extends uses the methods of the class it inherits from, beyond that though....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Faculty.java you have:
    super(firstName,lastName,streetAddress,zipCode,phoneNumber,department,ssn,salary);

This is physically calling the constructor of CollegeEmployee which has only five parameters. This is a compilation error.

A class may have variables that are not set in the constructor. You could have empty constructors and set the variables in another method.

Since there is an inheritance structure, you may only set the parent's variables via super().

Comment: "you may only set the parent's variables via super()." Good to know. That helps clear up WHY it's doing what it's doing...thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `super()` call in the constructor invokes the parent class constructor. In this case, the parent class `CollegeEmployee`s constructor takes five arguments but is being pass eight which is incorrect.

See [Keyword super Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html), section *Subclass Constructors* in particular.

Comment: then my followup question becomes how I get `ssn, department and salary` from `CollegeEmployee` to `Faculty`? That's the piece I'm missing.

Comment: Faculty 'has' everything that `CollegeEmployee` has, there is no need to 'get it to it'. When you call super from `Faculty`, it will use the `CollegeEmployee` JOptionPane's in that constructor to set them.

Comment: @dann.dev...so in other words, I'm overthinking this? Just by calling `CollegeEmployee` FROM `Faculty` will invoke the methods to prompt for input...if that's what you're saying, this suddenly makes a lot more sense.